# finding the minimum number of edges in a graph whose connected component is complete

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science

Given an undirected graph, denote N as the number of vertices and E as the number of edges in the Graph. The Graph consists of k connected components where k <= N.

1. Assuming **each connected component is complete**, What is
   the minimum number of edges in G (as a function of N and k)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired graph $G$ is a disjoint union of complete graphs $K_{n_1}, K_{n_2}, \dots, K_{n_k}$.  Component $i$ has $n_i$ nodes and $\binom{n_i}{2}$ edges, so the problem is to find positive integers $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$ to minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n_i}{2}$$
subject to
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i = N.$$
For example, if $k=1$, then $n_1=N$, and $G$ has $\binom{N}{2}$ edges.
As another extreme example, if $k=N$, then $n_i=1$ for all $i$, and $G$ has $0$ edges.  If $k=2$, what values for $n_1$ and $n_2$ minimize the number of edges?

Comment: Well, I know the maximum number of edges I can have is ((n - k + 1) * (n - k))/2. But I don't know what you mean by minimizing that.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether $n$ and $k$ are both given (and the OP is asking about the Turan number) or whether just $n$ is given. When a question is ambiguous I think the nontrivial (or less trivial) interpretation should be preferred. But maybe the question is unambiguous and my reading skills are deficient.

Comment: Both n and k are given. I updated the question. Does it make sense now?